# How to use testdisk to restore Linux partition after Windows10 update

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

After windows10 update on dual boot machine it entered into grub-rescue mode. I partly resolved the issue thanks to this forum and Windows is running again but Ubuntu is not. I tried testdisk from a bootable USB but I do not know how to use testdisk. Can anyone tell me how to change the partition characteristics?

[image]

This is a screenshot. The partition starting at 12 is the windows partition. Where should I put an *, a P, a L etc.?
Thanks

Comment: Put `*` on `Linux`